# SMTP connect failed - PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am doing an assignment in my uni, and they allow me a server for sending outgoing emails.

My PHP code: (I am using PHPMailer library)

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'mailhub.xxxx.edu.au';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->SetFrom('no-reply@travnow.com', 'Test');

$mail->Subject = "I hope this works!";

$mail->MsgHTML('Blah');

$address = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "Test");

if (!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

The helpdesk guy say I would just need to use "mailhub.xxxx.edu.au" as mySMTP server with port 25 and authentication is IP based.

But then I got this error:

```
2017-05-17 07:44:08 Connection: opening to mailhub.xxxx.edu.au:25, timeout=300, options=array ( )
2017-05-17 07:44:08 Connection: opened
2017-05-17 07:44:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mailhub.xxxx.edu.au ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.1/8.15.1; Wed, 17 May
2017 17:44:08 +1000 (AEST)
2017-05-17 07:44:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO _
2017-05-17 07:44:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mailhub.xxxx.edu.au Hello infs3202-c25wl.xxxx.net [172.23.83.119] (may be forged), pleased to meet you 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 67108864 250-DSN 250-ETRN 250-STARTTLS 250-DELIVERBY 250 HELP
2017-05-17 07:44:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2017-05-17 07:44:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2017-05-17 07:44:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO _
2017-05-17 07:44:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mailhub.xxxx.edu.au Hello infs3202-c25wl.xxxx.net [172.23.83.119] (may be forged), pleased to meet you 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 67108864 250-DSN 250-ETRN 250-DELIVERBY 250 HELP
2017-05-17 07:44:08 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2017-05-17 07:44:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2017-05-17 07:44:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 mailhub.xxxx.edu.au closing connection
2017-05-17 07:44:08 Connection: closed 2017-05-17 07:44:08  SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Is that the error in my code or the server side?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Please make sure you base your code on the examples provided with PHPMailer, and use [the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Your code is based on an obsolete example.

Answer (score 1):

You are using smtp Auth method, so could you try to provide username and password to autheticate:

```
$mail->Username = "name@gmail.com";                 
$mail->Password = "super_secret_password";
```

Comment: They said: "authentication is IP based" and I am using uni wifi. So I am not really sure which username and password I should use in this case

Comment: In this case can you change the `$mail->SMTPAuth = true;` to `$mail->SMTPAuth = false;`

Comment: The server can send the email if I set it to `false` but Gmail will reject the email

Comment: Because from the error message, it says authetication problem. If ip based authentication , i am not so sure what does they mean ? do you have any hints for that ?

Comment: Is it this is correct host name - > `mailhub.xxxx.edu.au`

Comment: As far as i know, if it say `$mail->SMTPAuth = true;` , the script will look for username and password to authenticate.

Comment: Using my student email address does not work at all. 

I might ask them again tomorrow for more details :)

Thank for your help!